# Checking existence of file with underscore in file name in zsh

Tags: shell-script, zsh, filenames, special-characters

I am writing a very simple script which will link shared configuration files. For some reason it does not behave as i expected for file with underscore in name. Does _ (underscore) means something special in zsh?

The mentioned script as it is now:

```
#!/bin/zsh
STATIC_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/apps/config"
STATIC_CONFIG_FILES=("couchdb.yml" "database.yml" "elasticsearch.yml" "slurm_api.yml")


cd $1/config
ELEMENTS=${#STATIC_CONFIG_FILES[@]}
for (( i=0;i<$ELEMENTS;i++)); do
  if [ ! -L ${STATIC_CONFIG_FILES[${i}]} ]; then
    echo 'Linking '$STATIC_CONFIG_PATH'/'${STATIC_CONFIG_FILES[${i}]}
    ln -s $STATIC_CONFIG_PATH'/'${STATIC_CONFIG_FILES[${i}]}
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. There is no underscore mistery

`slurm_api.yml` is `${STATIC_CONFIG_FILES[4]}` so the `for` should be like a

```
for (( i=1;i<=$ELEMENTS;i++)); do
```